# How to get the body content from a PHP-generated HTML page?

Tags: java, php, html

I am trying to get the content of an HTML page, using this code:

```
String malSearch = "http://myanimelist.net/anime.php?letter=" + firstLetter;
URL url = new URL(malSearch);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
int len = 0;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    baos.write(buf, 0, len);
}
String body = new String(baos.toByteArray(), encoding);
```

It works fine, but it doesn't give me what I really want. It gives me this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 </head>
 <body style="margin:0px">
  <iframe src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=9&xinfo=6-122029399-0 0NNN RT(1404149034204 2) q(0 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1) B12(4,315,0) U1&incident_id=124001330081285077-564449081699338326&edet=12&cinfo=4ee46646c753833e04000000" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 124001330081285077-564449081699338326</iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

when it should give me the whole page (approximately 800 lines).

I think it's due to the fact this is a website using PHP, but I'm not really sure. Can someone tell me how I could get the whole HTML content?

Here's the page I'm trying to get the content from: http://myanimelist.net/anime.php?letter=A

Comment: Why would the website using PHP make any difference to the HTML?

Comment: Why would anyone care what language a server is using the generate html? The server could have an army of infinite monkeys banging on typewriters with an industrial OCR system to digitize the paper output. Would you care if that's the case? All you get is html anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This site uses a service called Incapsula.
The website admins configured Incapsula to prevent bots from accessing it's content.

I suggest you contact the admins and ask to be whitelisted,
Trying to bypass the system will likely get you banned and blacklisted.

Comment: Hi Guys, I'm getting same error due to with Incapsula while using API's with android mobile app development. For android data requests are considering like bot's. How to solve this issue with android??

Comment: are you the site owner? if so, contact Incapsula support. If not, contact the site owner.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the HTML you are getting back from the server contains addresses for other pages that should be loaded. Your client should get the other pages and retrieve them if you want the page as it is shown in a web browser.

It makes no difference what the site is using.

EDIT: Read the error message carefully and you will find this error:

`Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 124001330081285077-`

So something went wrong with your call or maybe the server doesn't like your agent (it is expecting a browser like IE or Chrome)

Yep, something is wrong with your call. I was able to call the page and get a response without the error:

```
<html>
<head>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
<script>
(function(){function getSessionCookies(){cookieArray=new Array();var cName=/^\s?incap_ses_/;var c=document.cookie.split(";");for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){key=c[i].substr(0,c[i].indexOf("="));value=c[i].substr(c[i].indexOf("=")+1,c[i].length);if(cName.test(key)){cookieArray[cookieArray.length]=value}}return cookieArray}function setIncapCookie(vArray){try{cookies=getSessionCookies();digests=new Array(cookies.length);for(var i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){digests[i]=simpleDigest((vArray)+cookies[i])}res=vArray+",digest="+(digests.join())}catch(e){res=vArray+",digest="+(encodeURIComponent(e.toString()))}createCookie("___utmvc",res,20)}function simpleDigest(mystr){var res=0;for(var i=0;i<mystr.length;i++){res+=mystr.charCodeAt(i)}return res}function createCookie(name,value,seconds){if(seconds){var date=new Date();date.setTime(date.getTime()+(seconds*1000));var expires="; expires="+date.toGMTString()}else{var expires=""}document.cookie=name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"}function test(o){var res="";var vArray=new Array();for(test in o){switch(o[test]){case"exists":try{vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+typeof(eval(test)))}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+e)}break;case"value":try{vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+eval(test).toString())}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+e)}break;case"plugins":try{p=navigator.plugins;pres="";for(a in p){pres+=(p[a]["description"]+" ").substring(0,20)}vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugins="+pres)}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugins="+e)}break;case"plugin":try{a=navigator.plugins;for(i in a){f=a[i]["filename"].split(".");if(f.length==2){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin="+f[1]);break}}}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin="+e)}break}}vArray=vArray.join();return vArray}var o={navigator:"exists","navigator.vendor":"value",opera:"exists",ActiveXObject:"exists","navigator.appName":"value",platform:"plugin",webkitURL:"exists","navigator.plugins.length==0":"value"};try{setIncapCookie(test(o));document.createElement("img").src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWKMTFSR=1&e="+Math.random()}catch(e){img=document.createElement("img");img.src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWKMTFSR=1&e="+e}})();
</script>
<script>
(function() { 
var z="";var b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for (var i=0;i<b.length;i+=2){z=z+parseInt(b.substring(i, i+2), 16)+",";}z = z.substring(0,z.length-1); eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+z+')'));})();
</script></head>
<body>
<iframe style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" src="http://content.incapsula.com/jsTest.html" id="gaIframe"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main content on that page is loaded in the `<iframe>` tag. In that tag you can see the content url.

```
String malSearch = "http://myanimelist.net//_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=9&xinfo=6-122029399-0 0NNN RT(1404149034204 2) q(0 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1) B12(4,315,0) U1&incident_id=124001330081285077-564449081699338326&edet=12&cinfo=4ee46646c753833e04000000";
URL url = new URL(malSearch);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
```