# Wordpress site is not showing on Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

I have a site [www.mathildaparadeiser.com](http://www.mathildaparadeiser.com/) that is showing a white screen of death on Chrome. All other browsers seem fine.

Removed all plugins but still being shown. Chrome is updated and Wordpress also. Looking in Chrome Tools I get this first error

VM100:1 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Any ideas what would be causing this? Have debugged all I can.

Comment: The site loads with PHP errors. Also it may help to add a screen shot of what you see and describe what you expect. As it is now, the question isn't specific enough and you're not going to get answers.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any chrome extension plugins ?

Your site has uses a service called Incapsula. The website admins configured Incapsula to prevent bots from accessing it's content.

Please read here more :-
[How to get the body content from a PHP-generated HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496114/how-to-get-the-body-content-from-a-php-generated-html-page)

Some times your site contents loads, some time it shows a captcha. Check with your Hosting provider to understand.